# Java Script Functions Doesn't work After Error in One Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

I'm working with Asp.net Mvc and I Use Java script after i get error in A Function In Java Script other functions of page doesn't work until i refresh the page . so how can i handle errors for this problem?

Comment: for that you have to resolve the error :)

Comment: You can wrap the potentially problem block of code with `try .. catch` construct

Comment: @hindmost for null data catch is not happen for example i have data and it's null but when i access to data.id it gets error and catch is not happen

Comment: Where is your code? Without the code we only can guess

Comment: thankyou i think i have to handle null data by my self and use try catch for other thinks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with JavaScript is that if the engine finds an error in your page, usually doesn't execute the code beyond that error.

The only thing you could do to handle this is to remove the errors.

**EDIT:**

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp) you can see the *most universal* way of handling errors.

Comment: I remove errors but some times with error in data error in java script happens and it's caused by data how can i solve it?

Comment: I don't really understand what you say about errors being caused by data. Can you give me an example?

Comment: for example data is a model and i can access on it with data.id but when it's null it gets error and it always has data and id

Comment: Then make sure data is not null before using it. There is no universal way to handle errors. I've edited the question with a link which i think might help you. Implement `try ... catch ...` to **prevent** errors.

Comment: thankyou i think there isn't any way expect try catch and i have to handle null data by my self ;)